# Get path to font file, AtBeginDocument

Tags: fontspec, luaotfload

Using lualatex, TeXlive 2023. I am on Linux, but this question must apply to any platform, not just Linux. OpenType fonts, not necessarily provided by TeXlive.

Pseudo-code:

```
\documentclass{article} % compile with lualatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Some Font} % pick anything *otf that might be in TeX or elsewhere.
\typeout{MainFontWithPath=\whateverItIs}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

When `luaotfload` loads a font, surely it knows the path to that font at the very moment it is loaded. So if the user requests `\setmainfont{Some Font}` and it corresponds to `/path/to/somefont-regular.otf` and its family, this information is available internally. But the path and filename are not written to the log file, until very late in compile.

The `\listfiles` command does not list fonts, even if they are loaded. And I did not find a suitable `listfonts` or equivalent when I grepped the `luaotfload` directory.

My question: How can I get the list of `/path/to/fontfile.otf` shortly after the fonts are loaded, which I can then parse AtBeginDocument? I know how to parse, if I have the string.

I cannot do this with shell escape, or aux file.

Why I need to know: I work with custom fonts, that have metrics and kerning tweaked from time to time. I can use `\directlua` to get some information about the actual fonts used, and store that information in XMP metadata. Then, after passage of time, if I see that the same document produces different line breaks, I can look at the metadata to see which fonts changed (and restore the old font version, if necessary). Unfortunately, the code to parse a font file must know the path to the file, and the filename.otf.

Closely related question: I know how the `/path/to/filename.otf` is written in Linux. How is it written in Windows or Mac?

Comment: The question would be easier to answer if it included a MWE with the general surrounding setup.

Comment: Also while this is easy enough for modern fonts, for legacy fonts (everything involving .tfm files) this gets rather tricky since generally TeX might only know the TFM file at the beginning of the run. Do you want to know the TFM path then or just fail?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I never use legacy fonts. Never. Only OpenType *otf. Working with custom document class that will not load a legacy font. So, just fail for *tfm would be OK, because it will not happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the `filename` in the fonttable:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{fontpath.lua}
local func = luatexbase.new_luafunction'getfontpath'
token.set_lua('getfontpath', func)

local fontid = {token.create'tex_numexpr:D', token.create'tex_fontid:D'}

lua.get_functions_table()[func] = function()
  token.put_next(fontid)
  local id = token.scan_int()
  local fonttable = font.getfont(id)
  if not fonttable then
    tex.error('No such font', {'Unable to determine filepath for non-existing font'})
  end
  local path = fonttable.filename
  if not path then
    local properties = fonttable.properties
    path = properties and properties.filename
    path = path or kpse.find_file(fonttable.name, 'tfm') or tex.error'Unable to determine font path' or ''
  end
  tex.sprint(path)
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article} % compile with lualatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\lua_load_module:n{fontpath}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}
\typeout{MainFontWithPath=\getfontpath \font \relax}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Here in `\getfontpath \font \relax`, `\font` can be replaced with any TeX font specification. `\font` stands for the current font, while e.g. `\textfont 0` would give the path of math font family 0 in text style (that wouldn't work in the preamble though since there the math fonts aren't loaded yet).

Comment: Do you plan to add this interface to luaotfload?

Comment: @egreg Not really, it's just font.getfont().filename with some error fallbacks added, not sure how useful that would be in luaotfload. You can convince me otherwise though if you would consider it useful.

Comment: Thanks. Will investigate further. As @egreg noted, this might be something worth adding to `luaotfload` in the future. It might possibly be helpful to those who wonder why why a PDF created by an online service, does not typeset the same as on the home computer (because they are using different font files, with the same font name).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I put your code to good use. See my answer below yours.

Comment: @egreg I made use of Marcel's code. See answer I posted under his.

Answer (score 2):

Using the excellent code by Marcel Krüger, I propose a neater interface for storing and accessing the font properties.

```
\documentclass{article} % Compile with lualatex.
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\lua_load_module:n{fontpath} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709343/4427 for the code

\NewDocumentCommand{\storefontinfo}{mm}
 {% #1 = symbolic name, #2 = font declaration
  \railg_fontinfo_store:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getfontinfo}{mm}
 {% #1 = symbolic name, #2 = property
  \prop_item:cn { g_railg_fontinfo_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__railg_fontinfo_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \railg_fontinfo_store:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  #2
  \tl_set:Ne \l__railg_fontinfo_temp_tl { \getfontpath\font }
  \prop_new:c { g_railg_fontinfo_#1_prop }
  \prop_gput:cne { g_railg_fontinfo_#1_prop } { name } { \fontname\font }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l__railg_fontinfo_temp_tl
   {% no information
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_railg_fontinfo_#1_prop } { path } { ?? }
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_railg_fontinfo_#1_prop } { size } { 0 }
   }
   {
    \prop_gput:cnV { g_railg_fontinfo_#1_prop } { path } \l__railg_fontinfo_temp_tl
    \prop_gput:cne { g_railg_fontinfo_#1_prop } { size }
     { \file_size:V \l__railg_fontinfo_temp_tl }
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\storefontinfo{default}{}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif} % Or any font that TeX can find.
\newfontfamily{\test}{Apple Symbols}

\storefontinfo{main}{\normalfont}
\storefontinfo{main-it}{\normalfont\itshape}
\storefontinfo{test}{\test}
\storefontinfo{sf}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

The filesize of the default font is \getfontinfo{default}{size} bytes.

It was found at \getfontinfo{default}{path}.

The internal name is \getfontinfo{default}{name}.

\bigskip

The filesize of the main font is \getfontinfo{main}{size} bytes.

It was found at \getfontinfo{main}{path}.

The internal name is \getfontinfo{main}{name}.

\bigskip

The filesize of the main italic font is \getfontinfo{main-it}{size} bytes.

It was found at \getfontinfo{main-it}{path}.

The internal name is \getfontinfo{main-it}{name}.

\bigskip

The filesize of the sans font is \getfontinfo{sf}{size} bytes.

It was found at \getfontinfo{sf}{path}.

The internal name is \getfontinfo{sf}{name}.

\bigskip

The filesize of the test font is \getfontinfo{test}{size} bytes.

It was found at \getfontinfo{test}{path}.

The internal name is \getfontinfo{test}{name}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even better! One caution: If the user (such as myself) is writing anything into XMP, then it may be necessary to perform some character escapes, because XMP has its own rules for characters. But a power XMP user would know that, or apply code that automatically escapes what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm, for the *otf fonts I use. Unable to investigate Type1,
since I do not know much about them in TeX.

Instead of using the `filecontents` method, as written above, I put the
Lua code into a `\directlua` command, which immediately follows
`\setmainfont`. In addition to `\typeout` I save the string
in a variable. Then other Lua code gets the
file size of the main font, now that I know where it is. The file size
is written into the harmless `CreatorTool` string in XMP metadata.
Those who do not use XMP might write the file size somewhere else, perhaps
even visible in the PDF, if the recipient of the PDF allows it.
Why filesize instead of something else? The filesize is easy to get without
having to parse file bytes. Also, I often forget to change the font
version number when I modify the font, but its filesize is not likely to
remain the same. Maybe file modification date would be useful, but I am
not sure that all font creators or platforms record it correctly.
I do not need to record the file name (I know it, and so does the PDF)
or its path (can be ascertained from the filesize).

In the example below, I edited Marcel's code, to remove error messages.
No point halting compile if the requested info cannot be determined.

If you use this, remember to attribute it to Marcel. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} % Compile with lualatex.
\usepackage{pdftexcmds} % Gets filesize.
\usepackage{xifthen} % My favorite for tests, in a larger document.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  local func = luatexbase.new_luafunction'getfontpath'
  token.set_lua('getfontpath', func)
  local fontid = {token.create'tex_numexpr:D', token.create'tex_fontid:D'}
  lua.get_functions_table()[func] = function()
  token.put_next(fontid)
  local id = token.scan_int()
  local fonttable = font.getfont(id)
  if fonttable then
    local path = fonttable.filename
  end
  if not path then
    local properties = fonttable.properties
    path = properties and properties.filename
    path = path or kpse.find_file(fonttable.name, 'tfm') or ''
  end
  tex.sprint(path)
  end
}% End directlua.
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif} % Or any font that TeX can find.
\edef\MainFontWithPath{\getfontpath \font \relax} % The \font was just set.
\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\equal{\MainFontWithPath}{}}{
  \edef\MainFontFileSize{0} % Could not get the actual value.
}{
  \xdef\MainFontFileSize{\pdf@filesize{\MainFontWithPath}}
}
\makeatother
% I write \MainFontFileSize, with other info, into CreatorTool in XMP.
% That is my own code in a custom documentclass, too elaborate for here.
% If you do that, remember that XMP has its own rules for escape characters.
% So, it might be a bad idea to record the path. Numerals are OK.
\begin{document}
Hello. The filesize of the main font is \MainFontFileSize\space bytes.\par
It was found at \MainFontWithPath.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a missing closing brace after `\equal{\MainFontWithPath}{}`

Comment: @egreg Fixed the code.

Comment: Why not using `\ifempty{\MainFontWithPath}` instead?

Comment: @egreg Certainly could have used `\ifempty`. Force of habit, due to use of custom code in other places.